# How to download data set into Colab? Stuck with a problem, it says "401 - Unauthorized"?

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I am trying to download Boat Dataset from Kaggle[ https://www.kaggle.com/clorichel/boat-types-recognition]. For downloading dataset  I am using, the code:
!pip install -U -q kaggle
!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!echo '{"username":"{user}","key":"{API key"}' > ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
!mkdir -p data
!kaggle datasets download -d clorichel/boat-types-recognition -p ./data
But I am unable to download it into colab, I am getting error, "401 - Unauthorized".
How may, I resolve the issue or is there any other best way to do so?

Comment: have u found the solution?I am also facing the same error

Comment: I've manually downloaded the data, I am no longer working through collab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do generate new API Token from your kaggle account ,it may have expired in past.
And put it into any of your google drive folder ,in google colab set your current working directory as that folder, and then visit the kaggle ,copy API command and with "!+ API command" without quotes in google colab you will be able to download it.

Comment: Yes I've found it.